# How do you convert a list of characters and bytes into a list of pure bytes?

Tags: python, list

I have a list which is a mixture of characters and bytes, which looks like this :

```
myData = ['a', '\x65', 'B', '\x66\x69', 'C']
```

I want to convert this list into a byte array, so this :

```
myByteArray = ['\x61' , '\x65', '\x42', '\x66', '\x69', '\x43']
```

What I have tried so far is a simple display on myData --

```
myData = ['a', '\x65', 'B', '\x66\x69', 'C']
print " ".join(hex(ord(n)) for n in myData)
```

Since there is an element in the array that happens to be two bytes, it throws this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 3, in <module>
    print " ".join(hex(ord(n)) for n in myData)
  File "./test.py", line 3, in <genexpr>
    print " ".join(hex(ord(n)) for n in myData)
TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 2 found
```

How can I convert my original list, myData, into a byte array, myByteArray?

Comment: There's no way to get Python to depict a regular ASCII character as an escaped sequence, unless you turn it into the equivalent string. `'a'` and `'\x61'` are the same character, and Python will always print it as `'a'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can merge them all and split again to get the individual chars, like:

```
   output_list = [hex(ord(c)) for c in ''.join(myData)]
```

Trying it out,

```
>>> myData = ['a', '\x65', 'B', '\x66\x69', 'C']
>>> [hex(ord(c)) for c in ''.join(myData)]
['0x61', '0x65', '0x42', '0x66', '0x69', '0x43']
```

Comment: I suspect that will fail if you feed it a byte outside the ASCII range.

Comment: @MarkRansom I tried for some non-ASCII chars and it seems to work

Answer (score 1):

If you actually want a`list`of mutable bytes rather than one of immutable one-character strings, you could do it this way:

```
myData = ['a', '\x65', 'B', '\x66\x69', 'C', '\xff']

myByteArray = bytearray(''.join(myData))

print " ".join(hex(byte) for byte in myByteArray)
# 0x61 0x65 0x42 0x66 0x69 0x43 0xff
```

If a`list`of one-character strings is OK, all you need is:

```
myByteArray = list(''.join(myData))
```